# Submiting a form in a fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, fancybox

Is it possible to create a form to be submitted within a fancybox.

```
<a class="assignScoreValues" href="/quality/assign-score-values/id/1">Assign Score Values</a>
```

Then in the controller I display a form to be submitted.  I can't redirect as I will lose the information on the original page.

I'm thinking that it's not possible?

Comment: Why not submit the form via AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit the form with AJAX using Jquery and `serializeArray()`. To use an HTML link for for submission:

```
<a onclick="var data=jQuery('#form_id').serializeArray();
            $.ajax(
            {
                url:'url/to/post',
                type:'POST',
                data:data,
                success:
                    function(data){
                        //do something on success, for example close fancybox:
                        $.fancybox.close();
                }
            });
            return false;
            "
href="javascript:void(0);">Save Form</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox window is a part of the HTML of a parent one. So if your fancybox don't consist of the iframe the submitting in the fancybox will reload your parent page.

So the obvious (and the only I think) way to submit form correctly is to do it via AJAX. Then you can close the fancybox using `$.fancybox.close()` method.